# How to store picture(s) in a hyperledger blockchain channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

In my Hyperledger fabric project, I have a scenario where one of the asset is of type (images). How do I handle this asset in chaincode and are there any samples i can refer to (preferebly node.js)?

Answer (score 1):

You can hold images as encrypted characters such like base64 in Fabric Network.
That was once mentioned in IBM DeveloperWorks Blog, but I can't find the article.

If you use Hyperledger Composer, I think assigning an image to a property of the asset is useful.

In my case, tx is submitted from node.js server like below.

```
'use strict'

const util = require('util');
var fs = require('fs');
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

const BusinessNetworkConnection = require('composer-client').BusinessNetworkConnection;
this.bizNetworkConnection = new BusinessNetworkConnection();
this.cardName = '<REPLACE_CARD_NAME>';

async function createAsset(imgPath) {
    try {
        // Connect to Fabric Network.
        let definition = await this.bizNetworkConnection.connect(this.cardName)
        let factory = definition.getFactory();

        // Create a new asset which have property for base64 image.
        let newAsset = factory.newResource('com.namespace.your', 'AssetName', 'assetId');
        newAsset.imageBase64 = await readFile(imgPath,'base64');

        // Add the Asset to AssetRegistry.
        let assetRegistry = await this.bizNetworkConnection.getAssetRegistry('com.namespace.your.AssetName');
        await assetRegistry.add(newAsset);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } finally {
        this.bizNetworkConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please suggest when to use composer Vs. build your own network. I'm bit confused now.

Comment: Design of relationships between assets, participants and transaction is easier with using Composer. This is just my opinion, but I think creating chaincode in golang tends to be more complex. In our project we use Fabric SDK and golang chaincode only when we cannot do something (e.g. capturing block events, multiplying channels dynamically) with Composer's function.

Comment: I have installed Composer, and went through creation of sample business network etc. but still not getting my head around how to delpoy what i have created in to a proper network and how to build application on it. I understand how to create my own network using shell scripts. but not able to get big picture of how composer works. Any reference / sample material you can refer to? may be like a hello world sample with application client interface?

Comment: Have you already tried these tutorials? It says about how to deploy chaincode (bna) to fabric network in them. 
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-tutorial
I haven't able to find any sample apps with client interface but, FYI, I think the one in article below is a comprehensive example of apps with Hyperledger Composer(sorry but it's written in Japanese, please use translation software).
https://qiita.com/smatsui@github/items/a67efff76c1e3519b815